# How to deal with a professor who grades assignments and exams incorrectly

Tags: professorship, grading

I currently have a (graduate) professor who clearly does not understand the material she teaches at the level required by the course. This normally would not be a problem - I'm fine with educating myself via textbook - but unfortunately her inaccurate knowledge also extends to grading. I have no problem with studying hard for a difficult class, but I can't possibly know how to predict the exact incorrect ideas that the professor has and incorporate them into my work.

My first response was to *very, verrrrry diplomatically* approach the professor and talk to her about the questions - but she immediately became angry. I then talked to my advisor, who said that this isn't the first time she's heard of problems with this teacher. My advisor said that her only idea is for me to go to the head of the department, but I'd really prefer not to do this for two reasons:

1. Relatively small department; it's likely that this professor has
   a good relationship with the department head, and I would look bad
2. It seems like a "nuclear option" and I would prefer to avoid it
   (if possible)

This is my last semester of graduate coursework in molecular biology, and I have never had a problem like this before. I feel like my only option is to drop the course - without it, I would still have all my coursework requirements fulfilled - but I don't want to have a W on my transcript.

I have been unable to come up with a satisfactory way to resolve the problem.

**Possibly helpful additional information**

- I have talked to other students in the class; all (of the six I have talked to about the issue) have experienced similar problems in grading
- I have confirmation from other teachers that my answers are correct, but they don't want to confront a colleague (and I can't fault them for this)
- I don't *dislike* the teacher; she seems like a relatively OK person. I just wish she understood the content better
- The teacher can't possibly have a grudge against me, since I had never met her before the class
- I'm  very interested in what this class covers, which is why I took it despite not needing to
- I have taught some of this material at the undergraduate and graduate level; I understand it's difficult stuff. It's more the teacher's attitude towards grading that is the problem.

Comment: Are the "incorrect ideas" not delivered in lectures or reading assigned in addition to the text?

Comment: @BobBrown the textbook is correct, but every lecture is riddled with errors.

Comment: So, if I now understand the problem, you know what incorrect ideas are being presented, but not which ones will be reflected in the grading.  I think I should wait for someone with more experience in academia than I to answer this question, but at the moment, I'm in favor of the nuclear option, with an incorrectly graded paper in your hand.

Comment: "I currently have a (graduate) professor who clearly does not understand the material she teaches at the level required by the course. This normally would not be a problem - I'm fine with educating myself via textbook " then why are you wasting time and money in graduate school?

Comment: @emory: Often people want a credential that shows they know the material.

Comment: @emory: Because for one thing, it's pretty darned hard to get a job in academia or research without a PhD union card.

Comment: @emory: (1) Getting guidance on *what* literature to read, (2) interacting with experts when you have questions, (3) achieving certifications needed for many jobs (academic and otherwise), (4) getting started with a research/publishing career, (5) developing a network of colleagues to help with that research, etc.?

Comment: @DanielR.Collins All of those are good reasons to go to graduate school, but I question whether they are happening for the OP.  When I was a graduate student, I always thought my professors were experts in their field.  It would have been a big problem for me if I thought they were not.

Comment: @emory: Just because someone is an expert in their field doesn't mean that he is an expert at whatever he is teaching. I, for one, was once asked to do problem sessions in a topic I had no clue about, and learned as I went. I didn't pretend to know more than I actually did, though.

Comment: Which subject is this OP? Some branch of Maths or something else?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36369/discussion-on-question-by-jan-vincent-how-to-deal-with-a-professor-who-grades-as).

Comment: This is not *nearly* the "nuclear option".  Going to the department chair is about three levels below that.

Comment: How is it possible that you taught some of this material at the graduate level before and are now taking a graduate course on it?

Comment: This is not uncommon in the biological sciences, especially in small departments.

Comment: I have been in this very same situation. I confronted the lecturer, complaining my answers were correct, yet my grade did not reflect that - she quickly became angry, threatened that I would not be allowed to pass the exam if I continue to behave this way(pointing out her errors). But I was confident in my work, so I was planning to use the "nuclear option" the next day. However, she had corrected my grade by then. Your teacher is clearly not doing her job well - you have every right to nuke her. If she's going to be angry at criticism, she should not be in academia at all.

Comment: Could you clarify your reasoning on these actions? You're afraid that going to the department chair would make you look bad, but that badmouthing this professor by gossiping to her coworkers won't. I don't understand this logic.

Comment: I wonder how this turned out? Would love a quick update-edit to the question.

Answer (score 110, accepted):

Not a definitive answer, since I’m a postdoc with comparatively limited experience of such conflict situations, but I do have a few suggestions.  They aim to:

- maximise the chance of getting better grading without ruffling too many feathers;
- give you solid documentation if you *do* end up escalating the complaint;
- minimise the embarrassment in case it turns out that you’re misunderstanding something and your lecturer’s grading is defensible after all.

**If you confront the teacher again, do so by email rather than in person.**  This has several advantages.  Firstly, it allows you to look over what you’ve written and make sure you’re phrasing everything as tactfully as possible.  Secondly, it gives her time to (hopefully) get over any initial anger/embarrassment and give a considered response.  Confronted on a sensitive topic in person, it’s easy to get flustered and defensive, and entrenched in a position it’s difficult to climb down from later.  Finally, if she doesn’t respond constructively, you have the exchange in writing, so are on firmer ground for escalating the issue to the department head.

If possible, **phrase the question/request so that your desired outcome is also palatable for her.**  If you argue that she’s fundamentally misunderstanding the course material, she’s pretty unlikely to accept that — admitting that one’s wrong about something is already difficult, admitting one’s incompetent is a whole lot harder again. Instead, you could say that (e.g.) you have learned some of the material previously, and so know it with a different viewpoint from hers (and maybe give a couple of examples here, ideally with sources in well-established literature) and you would like to check that this angle will also be acceptable for work on the course.  I’m not saying you should say exactly that — but look for something that allows her to concede that your understanding is correct, without having to admit (to you or herself) that hers is wrong; and down the line this makes it easier for her to improve her understanding of the subject, rather than remaining antagonistic towards your suggestions.  On the other hand, if she *does* defend her current approach, this gives her a chance to lay out her case more clearly and carefully.

**If you do this and she still doesn’t engage constructively, you’re now on very solid ground to escalate the complaint.**  You have a written record of your good-faith effort to sort this out tactfully.  You have specific examples where she has doubled down on her misunderstanding of the material.  (I’d suggest double-checking these with your advisor or another faculty member to be absolutely sure you’re right about them.)  Even if the head of department supports this teacher in general, it will be comparatively difficult for them to dismiss the complaint or paint you as a troublemaker.

Comment: Thank you. I think this is the best option that I have available to me.

Answer (score 34):

My recommendation would be to **withdraw from the course**. I'd almost go so far as to say you have a prime opportunity to do so in this case: it's not a required course, *and* you know you can learn it on your own, *and* you have other things that take priority with your time. Granted how defensive she got (and noncommittal your advisor was), the overall trajectory seems to be some combination of (a) getting into an ongoing and escalating dispute with her, (b) contending with department interactions over an extended period, (c) triggering end-of-course grade disputes, etc. This threatens to be a huge sink in your time and emotional energy, so I would recommend simply sidestepping the whole issue as the best option.

Now: The one thing that makes me hesitate with this advice is that I don't have very deep experience with what a effect a "W" has on a PhD transcript. Personally, I have a whole bunch of W's on my undergraduate transcript (albeit none in my major), and they have never been an issue or mentioned in any context: not on applying to graduate school, getting industry employment, or getting a full-time lecturer position.

**Edit:** Thanks to @vadim123 for the comment: "Nobody cares what you have on your PhD transcript. They care about (1) what you've published, (2) what's in your thesis, and as a distant third (3) your GPA. Oh, and (0) what your letters of recommendation say about you." Sounds about right.

Comment: I'm not certain, but my sense is that a W would require explanation. And that is not something you want to need to give. Whereas a less-good-pass is likely a non-issue and won't even register as anything but 'fine'.

Comment: Good point. I think this question is more about "what should I do", and if OP do not like the nuclear option (where most serious argument would escalate anyway), the other clear way is the W.

Comment: Nobody cares what you have on your PhD transcript.  They care about (1) what you've published, (2) what's in your thesis, and as a distant third (3) your GPA.  Oh, and (0) what your letters of recommendation say about you.

Answer (score 10):

Find out the final-grade appeals process in your department/at your university. (Where I am the procedure is department-level, but that may or may not be the case where you are.) Keep every assignment your professor has graded; separately, write up where and how the grading is incorrect.

Follow the procedure to the letter. Be apologetic and accommodating (as you have here) rather than angry. Explain that you did try to raise this with the professor directly, and the result was not positive.

This deflects the situation into being about your grade, which is impersonal, rather than a personal dispute between you and the professor, which you (probably quite correctly, graduate departments being as clannish as they are) wish to avoid.

Answer (score 6):

Realistically, how much do the actual grades matter in your program? In many programs they do not matter as long as you pass. The main purpose of graduate courses is for you to learn so you can do better research, and it seems you have achieved that goal.

If this is the case, a reasonable option would be just to ignore it (you are about to finish your graduate coursework anyway) and just focus on the most important part - research.

Comment: Really?  In the two graduate programs I know about, grades are A, B, and C-U-later.

Comment: @BobBrown So A and B pass. Does it really matter if you get an A or a B as long as you pass?

Comment: Well, it mattered to me.

Comment: @BobBrown nothing wrong with that. But I think it is important to point out to OP that in the grand scheme of things, grades are a minor part of the PhD.

Comment: Grades are not so unimportant.  If you ever go into industry or seek a teaching position or even research position at a lesser institution, they may ask for your grad school GPA.  And it can very well matter.

Comment: @Chan-HoSuh I don't doubt this happens but, if it actually matters beyond 'good enough', then the recipients are fooling themselves. GPAs from different schools are radically incommensurable. (Mine didn't even produce GPAs for graduate students.) Those which only count A/B as passes, for example - well, guess what? Almost all students get at least a B in all their courses. Somewhere else, the story will be different. Which doesn't mean it doesn't matter - if people count it, it can matter. But some places just want to see you did OK. The rest is irrelevant.

Comment: Those aware of grad school grading schemes are likely to view B grades very suspiciously, especially if you didn't produce a very strong research output.

Comment: If you are at a proper University and have mediocre grades that is much better than A passes from a diploma mill . Look at the MIT in the USA and compare it to the MIT in New Zealand .This is the Manakau Institute of Technology .The lecturers at MIT   NZ would not get into the MIT   USA     as freshmen.

Comment: _especially if you didn't produce a very strong research output_ — So don't do that then.

Comment: If the grading is incorrect then there _will_ be people who pass or fail incorrectly.

Answer (score 5):

Basically, I agree with @PLL. I wouldn't tell to the professor directly that she is wrong. It may be hard for her to realize that she is wrong if you directly tell her that. Also, I agree with you in a part of preferring of not going to the head of the department. She is a professor and it is a little bit sensitive topic.

Still, I think she should know that she teaches wrong because students have an issue with a wrong teaching, and she has an issue even though she doesn't know that (or she knows but she doesn't want to change?).

I would send her a mail. You may write that you are confused because you thought that some other thing is correct and now you don't know anymore which approach to take. Also you can ask her for a help. Of course you don't need a help but she should think more about the problem and at the same time she shouldn't feel that she is under attack because she may start to act "too defensive". You can be stubborn in your reply (e.g. "I really thought differently/ I would like to know which part of my approach is wrong so I don't make any mistake/ What should I change", etc.).

Answer (score 4):

Beyond your department, your university most likely has an ombudsperson who can help you navigate this issue. They may be an essential resource, since they are helpfully outside of your small department, and should (hopefully) be knowledgeable and well-versed in the areas you need: grade disputes, university policy/procedure, academic politics, etc. Reasons why it might be good to get this person involved:

- You don't know what is going on in the professor's life.  We don't have enough information to form a conclusion about the cause of the situation, but it's worth entertaining a number of explanations for conspicuous behavior, and the ombudsperson might be able to help.
- I've also once heard through the grapevine of a department head complicit in assigning a gravely unqualified teacher to a course, and it would almost certainly be unwise to try and force *that* issue by yourself.

Comment: Is it a plausible scenario, given the information we have, that the professor has mental problems? No it isn’t. Ungrounded speculations like this does not belong in an answer imo.

Comment: The advice to get a third party involved (ombudsman or similar) is the saving grace here, and by quick glance not covered by the other answers.

Comment: @winther My main goal was giving examples of why the student might want to approach an ombudsperson without getting exhaustive. That said, your comment did make me realize I could invert the order of the answer, and make this relationship clearer. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

In short: approach the professor with a **detailed, full and rigorous explanation** on why your solution is correct. Deal with it professionally, and base your claims on hard facts alone, not your personal opinions.

*Longer answer:* I am not *completely* convinced by your story. That is, I do believe that there might be an ambiguous marking criteria going on in your course, but I don't see how you drew the categorical conclusion that "the teacher doesn't understand what she is teaching". That's only your opinion. The fact your advisor said something about the professor also doesn't establish much. He/she might have said something without thinking much about it.

So I believe you should simply deal professionally with the matter: stick to facts, find out precisely where the marking is incorrect and send an email/contact your teacher. This seems like a quite simple story. You say that "the teacher got angry" when approached. I'm also not convinced this is the full story. People do not generally simply get angry when approached. You need to figure out the **precise** conversation that led to her getting angry, if indeed.

Comment: I've had a total of three teachers over the years with grading issues.  Facts didn't matter to any of them.

Comment: Again, I am not convinced. What does it mean "facts didn't matter to them"? Obviously, *some* facts did matter to them. So your explanation is almost surely incomplete. Are you claiming that because of their ego they decided not to admit their mistake? Or perhaps because they are afraid of the consequences of admitting a mistake? Or are you claiming that they are sociopaths who arbitrarily give grades, and then they become opaque to students' complaints? Or what exactly are you saying?

Comment: I mean that proving your case didn't matter to them.  They're the teacher, they're right, you're wrong.

Comment: Again, your explanation is lacking. I believe that this is the impression you got, but don't take what you think is true for granted.

Comment: In one case it was totally clear-cut:  The professor insisted there was only one way to do something, I had studied a system that did it differently.  This same professor was unable to answer a **very** simple question in class, also despite the confused student asking three times.  Another student finally piped up with a correct, one-word answer.

Comment: Your story doesn't prove that facts didn't matter to the professor. It proves only that the professor was possibly unaware that there is another approach to the problem, and made a mistake by claiming there's only one approach.

Comment: I presented the counterexample to him, he still marked me wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Most universities have some sort of grading appeal process, so you can use that if necessary.

However, if you are wanting to do something a bit more diplomatic, the only suggestion I have is to try and get her to recognise that she is incorrect. Fin the most egregious error in her marking, preferably one that you can point to material that shows she is incorrect. Then you can do something like 'I really don't understand why this ... is wrong and would like to go through it with you'. Teachers usually have office hours exactly for this, explaining what the student did wrong. During that discussion, you can say things like 'how does that reconcile with ...' and get the supporting material out. Or, 'the textbook says ..., but I am having trouble integrating that with ... (whatever she said)'. If you make it about you trying to understand, as she tries to explain it, she may well realise that what she's saying doesn't make sense. Avoid saying 'you are wrong' and make it much more like 'but I can't see how that fits with ...'

Answer (score -2):

***This way having a personal tutor assigned by the department (or collage) to each student is very important.***

Go to your personal tutor, and explain that you are finding it hard to understand why your answers are being marked as they are.   Ask your tutor to explain to you what you do not understand….

Make it all about your lack of understanding, including your lack of understanding of the books.

Comment: Maybe it's important, but in many academic cultures it simply isn't the standard.  What do you propose if the OP doesn't have a personal tutor?

Answer (score -3):

It is worth knowing that what is taught in coursework or printed in course texts, can be many years behind research frontiers.

If the coursework is in the professor's field of specialisation, there is a very good chance that her knowledge is years ahead of the text.

Google Scholar is your friend.

Comment: The OP states that _I have confirmation from other teachers that my answers are correct_.

Comment: @scaaahu other teachers might be in a fight.

Comment: @Nemo Other students have similar problems and the OP himself taught some of the materials at undergrad and graduate levels. Everybody is wrong and only the teacher in question is right?

Comment: @scaaahu not necessarily, but often in such cases there are at least two groups (of professors, students etc.) on different sides. It's well possible that the persons the OP talks with are just those close to him, who logically belong to the "party" other than the allegedly problematic teacher's.

Comment: @Nemo I have no interest to engage in a debate about whether the teacher is right. We are supposed to help the OP to resolve the problem (he does not want to withdraw the class). This answer assumes that the OP is at fault (the teacher is right about her lecture and grading). That's why I had the comment. End of discussion here.

Comment: Figuring out whether the OP might be wrong, should also help the OP to solve the problem.

Comment: @Dilworth But the question isn't, "Am I correct in thinking my teacher's grading is wrong?". We haven't been asked to analyse samples of the teacher's grading or anything along those lines. The question is, "How to deal with a professor who grades assignments and exams incorrectly?". If we start questioning the OP's axiom (that the grading is incorrect) then the answers become less useful to future readers of the question.

Comment: @JBentley, I'm not questioning the OP's belief in his/her axiom. I'm explaining the student the obvious: that he/she might be wrong, and that's why they need to stick to facts and not opinions on what the teacher understands. This way they can solve optimally the problem.